# Double integrals for reconstructing probablistic model

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, gamma-function

I am trying to reconstruct this probabilistic model,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\mu}\int^{\infty}_{0}P(N \geq n\, |\, L=l, T=t)\,e^{-\frac{l}{\mu}} dl &= \frac{1}{(n-1)!\mu}\int^{\infty}_{0} \left\{ \int^{tl}_{0}e^{-y}y^{n-1}dy \right\}e^{-\frac{l}{\mu}}dl \\
&= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\{1+1/(t\mu)\}y}y^{n-1}dy \\
&= \frac{1}{(1+1/(t\mu))^{n}} = \left(\frac{t\mu}{1+t\mu}\right)^{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We know that $N$ follows a Poisson distribution. Such that,
\begin{equation}
 P(N \geq n) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^{\lambda}_{0}e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx.
\end{equation}
and also that $L$ is gamma distribution parameter.

I know how to get (using integration by parts),
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\{1+1/(t\mu)\}y}y^{n-1}dy = \frac{1}{(1+1/(t\mu))^{n}} = \left(\frac{t\mu}{1+t\mu}\right)^{n}
\end{equation}
But I have no idea how to get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(n-1)!\mu}\int^{\infty}_{0} \left\{ \int^{tl}_{0}e^{-y}y^{n-1}dy \right\}e^{-\frac{l}{\mu}}dl = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\{1+1/(t\mu)\}y}y^{n-1}dy
\end{equation}
I have tried different methods of approach, by parts, substitution, but to no avail. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left hand side of your expression is the Laplace transform of an integral from 0 to $tl$.

$\begin{align}
  & \int_{0}^{\infty }{\left\{ \int_{0}^{tl}{{{e}^{-y}}}{{y}^{n-1}}dy \right\}}{{e}^{-\frac{l}{\mu }}}dl= \int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\frac{l}{\mu }}}}\left\{ \int_{0}^{l}{{{e}^{-tp}}}{{(tp)}^{n-1}}tdp \right\}dl  =\mu \mathfrak{L}(f)\left( \frac{1}{\mu } \right)  
\end{align}$

where $\mathfrak{L}(f)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(y)={{e}^{-ty}}{{(ty)}^{n-1}}t$ and we have used the result that $\mathfrak{L}\left( \int_{0}^{l}{f(y)dy} \right)(s)=\frac{\mathfrak{L}\left( f \right)(s)}{s}$ for s = $\frac{1}{\mu}$.
Then

$\mathfrak{L}\left( f \right)\left( \frac{1}{\mu } \right)=\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\tfrac{y}{\mu }}}{{e}^{-ty}}{{(ty)}^{n-1}}tdy=}\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\tfrac{p}{t\mu }}}{{e}^{-p}}{{(p)}^{n-1}}dp=}\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\left( 1+\tfrac{1}{t\mu } \right)p}}{{p}^{n-1}}dp}$

and replace p with y to recover the right hand side of your integral equality.

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much.